# Can't run Tor on Mac Book pro

Tags: help, mac, connection

I have installed Tor Browser Version 7.5.6 - OS X (10.9+) for my Mac Book Pro, but can't start the browser. I click "Connect" and "Remove settings and connect" but I get the errors that I have pasted in this post.

Hope someone can help me with this problem

[image]

[image]

```
13/07/2018, 20.51.53.000 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '10.0.0.1:9150' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
13/07/2018, 20.51.53.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
13/07/2018, 20.51.53.000 [NOTICE] Switching to guard context "default" (was using "bridges") 
13/07/2018, 20.51.53.000 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '10.0.0.1:9150' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
13/07/2018, 20.51.53.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
13/07/2018, 20.51.53.000 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '10.0.0.1:9150' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
13/07/2018, 20.51.53.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
13/07/2018, 20.51.53.000 [NOTICE] You configured a non-loopback address '10.0.0.1:9150' for SocksPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted. 
13/07/2018, 20.51.53.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 10.0.0.1:9150 
13/07/2018, 20.51.53.000 [WARN] Could not bind to 10.0.0.1:9150: Can't assign requested address 
13/07/2018, 20.51.53.000 [WARN] Controller gave us config lines that didn't validate: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
```

Comment: Please read this and modify your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I recommend deleting the application, and re-installing.
Download the version of Tor compatible with your machine from [Tor Project](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en).

You can check whether your system is 64-bit or 32-bit by opening a terminal and typing `getconf LONG_BIT`.  The number returned determines which version of Tor you will download.